# Customize Countdown JS [Close]

Tags: jquery, countdown

I follow countdown library http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html and use this code to display timer

```
var def = 2 * 60 * 1000;
var now = new Date();
var timer = new Date(now.getTime() + def);
$('#countdown').countdown({until: timer});
```

And output is 3minutes but i need output 180 countdown 179, 178, 177.. 0. How to customize it?

**Solved with add :** `format: 'S'`

**To add in input text :** `layout:'<input type="text" value="{sn}">'`

Thanks Rahul Gupta and jeek online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/N86nK/2/)
JS Code:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 180);
$('#countdown').countdown({until: now, format: 'S'});
```

Comment: oh my god, it's only add format: 'S'. thanks you sir

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct so that it can help other users to find correct solution to the problem !

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what exactly you are looking for :

```
var def = 3 * 60 * 1000; 
var now = new Date();
var timer = new Date(now.getTime() + def);
$('#countdown').countdown({until: timer, format: 's'});
```